# How to simulate a button click in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am writing a program that should simulate clicking on submit in AJAX, after which the page should asynchronously reload. I wrote a program, that asynchronously reloads the page, but only if I click on the submit button.

Here is my program:

```js
$("#form_id").submit(function() {
    var str = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",      
        url: "../async_db.php",
        data: str,
        success: function(html) {
            $('#d_id').html(html);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: With *asynchronously reload* you mean: update the HTML without reloading?

Comment: Yes. I need to send a POST request, but without reloading the HTML

Comment: `$("#form_id").trigger("submit");`

Answer (score 0):

To reload a page after post data by ajax *asynchronously* you can use `location.reload()` at the end of the `submit()` function.

```
  $("#form_id").submit(function() {
                    var str = $(this).serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",      
                        url: "../async_db.php",
                        data: str,
                        success: function(html) {
                            $('#d_id').html(html);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                    location.reload();
                });
```